# Special characters displays as �

Tags: c#, text

In my code, I'm displaying some text in Windows Form StatusBar. This also includes user's full name. However, due to the local language, it will very likely contain letters like "š, č, ř, ě, í, á etc.". These all are displayed as "�". Do I need to somehow change the charset or something?

Comment: What is your code? Share us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very likely the font you are using in your form does not support Unicode characters.

Comment: Yep, seems to be so. Thanks.